# search icon is not displaying correct inside the <a href="<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array( 'class' => 'fa fa-search mfp-image' )); ?>"></a>

Tags: php, themes

```html
 <a href="images/portfolio/full/portfolio_3.png" class="fa fa-search mfp-image"></a>
 
 <a href="<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array( 'class' => 'fa fa-search mfp-image' )); ?>"></a>
```

Hi i have converted the anchor tag to wordpress theme and now the problem is that, when i hover over a picture then it show double quotes and greaterthan sighn with search icon (">) as like in the below picture
[image url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lgtB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for posting my question without research too much as my question is already anserved on stack overflow

Viktor[viktor](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/81006/viktor)

Post url[post url](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/274181/the-title-is-not-displaying-over-the-thumbnail)